Запятая/тире в предложении "как это делать он не знал"
Предложение:
"Только вот как это делать он не знал".
В книге не стоит запятая, а мне интуитивно кажется, что должна быть (или запятая, или тире).
А как правильно?

Возможны варианты с запятой и тире:
(1) Только вот как это делать, / он не знАл.
(2) Только вот кАк это делать — // он не знАл.
Пояснение
Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, союзное слово КАК, поэтому знак нужен. Перед союзом находятся частицы, возможно, поэтому пропущена запятая.
Запятая ставится по общему правилу, интонация нейтральная. Постановка тире допускается при логическом ударении на слове КАК, это авторский выбор.
В книге, вероятно, логического подчеркивания нет, а тогда пауза не слишком заметна.
